# What does exception signify AndroidKeystoreAesGcm: encountered a potentially transient KeyStore error, will wait and retry

Tags: android, android-keystore, tink

my current android application employs the `tink` library from google for encryption of data within my local database

```
   api 'com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.6.1'
```

my app `gradle` resembles this:-

android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

my project `gradle` resembles this:-

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:6.3.1'
    }
}
```

today i have started seeing these errors and ive no idea what that they mean, if i need to be concerned by them, or how to resolve them

```
2022-01-28 13:53:24.682 14506-14548/com.my.app W/AndroidKeystoreAesGcm: encountered a potentially transient KeyStore error, will wait and retry
    android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException: Key permanently invalidated
        at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:123)
        at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:154)
        at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:339)
        at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:171)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encryptInternal(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:84)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encrypt(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:68)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.validateAead(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:248)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getAead(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:165)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewMasterKey(AndroidKeysetManager.java:267)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:236)
```

also this message

```
2022-01-28 13:53:24.741 14506-14548/com.my.app W/AndroidKeysetManager: cannot use Android Keystore, it'll be disabled
    android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException: Key permanently invalidated
        at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:123)
        at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:154)
        at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:339)
        at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:171)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encryptInternal(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:84)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encrypt(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:72)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.validateAead(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:248)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getAead(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:165)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewMasterKey(AndroidKeysetManager.java:267)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:236)
```

here is my `tink` code which resides in my android application class

```
  private fun manageTink() {
        try {
            AeadConfig.register()
            authenticatedEncryption = generateNewKeysetHandle().getPrimitive(Aead::class.java)
        } catch (e: GeneralSecurityException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, GeneralSecurityException::class)
    private fun generateNewKeysetHandle(): KeysetHandle =
        AndroidKeysetManager
            .Builder()
            .withSharedPref(this@MyApplication, TINK_KEYSET_NAME, PREF_FILE_NAME)
            .withKeyTemplate(KeyTemplates.get("AES256_GCM"))
            .withMasterKeyUri(MASTER_KEY_URI)
            .build()
            .keysetHandle
```

do the above messages need addressing
how do i resolve them
what have i done wrong?